# Get location name after user tap on that : Google Indoor Map API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, indoor-positioning-system, google-indoor-maps

I m trying to get Google indoor maps to work inside my android application.

When I look at a building in Google maps with indoor information available it shows the name of the places in it.

When user click on that specific location then i want to open some dialog or different activity which contains information about this tapped location. For that this location name should be require to request some information to my server. Because that desire information should come from my application server side.

So my main question is that for indoor maps which i am able to see in below image. Is there any API to get name of tapped location ?

Image for Example :

[image]

Thanks
Saurabh

Answer (score 1):

When you tap at a location you can get coordinates of that location. All you need to do is just a reverse geocoding i.e. getting location from coordinates longitude & latitude.

```
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
             List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                        latitude, longitude, 1);                    
     } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Unable connect to Geocoder", e);
     }
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit for your answer. Is this true for Indoor map API also ?

Comment: I have not tried it for indoor map but technically speaking it should work. As on google map server those coordinates are saved with the name of that place so when you send the coordinates to it, it should return you the address of those coordinates. Address will contains the name of place.